# PostgreSQL is not starting after pg_rewind

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I am using `pg_rewind` as follows on the slave:

```
/usr/pgsql-11/bin/pg_rewind -D <data_dir_path> --source-server="port=5432 user=myuser host=<ip>"
```

Command is completing successfully with:

```
source and target cluster are on the same timeline
no rewind required
```

After that, I created `recovery.conf` on the new slave as follows:

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=<master_ip> port=5432 user=<uname> password=<password> sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
trigger_file = '/tmp/MasterNow'
```

After that I start PostgreSQL on the slave and check the status. I get the following messages:

```
]# systemctl status postgresql-11
● postgresql-11.service - PostgreSQL 11 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2019-05-02 10:36:11 UTC; 33min ago
     Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/
  Process: 26444 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 26450 (postmaster)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql-11.service
           ├─26450 /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/11/data/
           └─26458 postgres: startup   recovering 000000060000000000000008

May 02 11:09:13 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:13 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:18 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:18 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:23 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:23 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:28 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:28 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:33 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:33 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:38 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:38 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:43 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:43 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:48 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:48 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:53 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:53 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
May 02 11:09:58 my.localhost postmaster[26450]: 2019-05-02 11:09:58 UTC LOG:  record length 1485139969 at 0/8005CB0 too long
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

On the master, the `pg_wal` directory looks as follows:

```
root@{/var/lib/pgsql/11/data/pg_wal}#ls -R
.:
000000010000000000000003  000000020000000000000006  000000040000000000000006  000000050000000000000008  archive_status
000000010000000000000004  00000002.history          00000004.history          00000005.history
000000020000000000000004  000000030000000000000006  000000050000000000000006  000000060000000000000008
000000020000000000000005  00000003.history          000000050000000000000007  00000006.history

./archive_status:
000000050000000000000006.done  000000050000000000000007.done
```

PostgreSQL logs from slave:

```
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9226]: [39-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC LOG:  entering standby mode
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9226]: [40-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 80 at 0/8005C78
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9226]: [41-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  switched WAL source from archive to stream after failure
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [35-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpqwalreceiver"
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [36-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  find_in_dynamic_libpath: trying "/usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpqwalreceiver.so"
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [37-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 0/8000000 on timeline 6
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [38-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sendtime 2019-05-03 06:08:58.348488+00 receipttime 2019-05-03 06:08:58.350018+00 replication apply delay (N/A) transfer latency 1 ms
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [39-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sending write 0/8020000 flush 0/0 apply 0/0
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [40-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sending write 0/8020000 flush 0/8020000 apply 0/0
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9226]: [42-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC LOG:  invalid resource manager ID 80 at 0/8005C78
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [41-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sendtime 2019-05-03 06:08:58.349865+00 receipttime 2019-05-03 06:08:58.35253+00 replication apply delay 0 ms transfer latency 2 ms
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [42-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sending write 0/8040000 flush 0/8020000 apply 0/0
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [43-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sending write 0/8040000 flush 0/8040000 apply 0/0
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [44-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  sending write 0/8040000 flush 0/8040000 apply 0/0
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [45-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC FATAL:  terminating walreceiver process due to administrator command
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [46-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 1 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [47-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 5 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [48-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 2 callbacks to make
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [49-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  exit(1)
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [50-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [51-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  shmem_exit(-1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9227]: [52-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  proc_exit(-1): 0 callbacks to make
May  3 06:08:58  postgres[9218]: [35-1] 2019-05-03 06:08:58 UTC DEBUG:  reaping dead processes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the standby is trying to recover along the wrong time line (5, I guess), does not follow the new primary to the latest time line and keeps hitting an invalid record in the WAL file.

I'd add the following to `recovery.conf`:

```
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

For a more detailed analysis, look into the PostgreSQL log file.

Comment: I got following on postgresql site:
`
When the target server is started for the first time after running pg_rewind, it will go into recovery mode and replay all WAL generated in the source server after the point of divergence. If some of the WAL was no longer available in the source server when pg_rewind was run, and therefore could not be copied by the pg_rewind session, it must be made available when the target server is started. This can be done by creating a recovery.conf file in the target data directory with a suitable restore_command.
`

Comment: Well, without seeing your log file it is hard to tell what exactly happened.

Comment: Ok. Can you please tell me how i can use restore_command with streaming replication where there are two different node (i.e master and server are different)

Comment: You need a shared directory (e.g. NFS) or a `restore_command` that uses `scp` or similar. Please add the relevant parts from the failing slave's PostgreSQL log file to the question.

Comment: log is to 'standard output stream'. Got only what is mentioned.

Comment: But the behavior of `pg_rewind` doesn't look good to me. It says both server are on same timeline but fails to start.

Comment: Well, then setup logging correctly in `postgresql.conf`. Without that information the question is unanswerable (I was guessing above).

Comment: Reading this again, I see "source and target cluster are on the same timeline". So there was no failover at all. I guess what is missing is the history. Was replication ever working? Then what happened? Why did you run `pg_rewind` at all?

Comment: Scenario is as follows:
I have 3 node cluster. 
Node 1 is primary and node2 and node3 is secondary/slave.
I have stopped node1 and did failover to node2. Now node2 is primary.
Then, i tried to make node3 as slave pointing to new master node2 and getting above error.

Comment: From node1 to node2/node3..replication was working fine.

Comment: But there was no failover, otherwise `pg_rewind` would not say that they are on the same time line. Please edit the question and add a comprehensive description of what happened, e.g. which commands you used.

Comment: I tried my whole configuration with `recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'` and working fine

Comment: Sorry, my sloppiness.